# 404 error with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I need to grab some data from a JSP page that does a select on a database and then put inside a div. I need to do this with ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    teste();
});

function teste() {
    var v1 = document.getElementById("selCodigo").value;
    alert(v1);

    $.ajax({       
       type : "GET",
       data : "turma="+v1,
       url : "busca-notas.jsp",       
       success : function(resposta){
           alert("DEU CERTO");
       },
       error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(thrownError);
           document.getElementById("notas").innerHTML = "ERRO";
       }
    });
}
```

I tested the variable `v1` and the value that it receives necessary, and in my JSP page, I do this:

```
String turmaSelecionada = request.getParameter("turma");
```

the problem is that the ajax content that does not feed into the div need, beyond what the `xhr.status` presents thrownError and a 404 error not found

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error, the error is going to be here: `url : "busca-notas.jsp",`

Comment: yes but this this page in the same directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either, `busca-notas.jsp` does not exist, or it is on a different server or path as the HTML calling the Ajax request.

Example: If your HTML and JavaScript is here:

```
http://www.example.com/somepath/page.html
```

and your PHP code is here:

```
http://www.example.com/otherpath/busca-notas.jsp
```

then you'll Need to use `url: "../otherpath/busca-notas.jps"`. There is an easy way to check: Open your HTML in the browser, remove the last bit of the path, and replace it with "busca-notas.jpg", and see what you're getting.

A 404 also means, your JSP code never gets executed.

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeessssssssssssssssssssssssss
worked
much, thank you so much
this is the best forum in the world: D

Answer (score 0):

This is saying the resource you are trying to do a GET to is not there. The path you are doing a GET to is probably incorrect. Can you tell the structure of your files (javascript/service files etc...). I would suggest using the browser developer tools or fiddler to debug what is going on.

Use F12 (windows) with browsers to get to the developer tools. Also the fiddler tool is great! http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

On a side note if you use console.log for debugging you will never go back to alerts :)

Comment: sorry but i did not
the busca-notas.jsp this in the same directory. not be possible path